# Best practice to check for available props or methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen many different ways of checking for available properties or methods in javascript.

```
if(typeof window.somePropOrMethod​ !== "undefined"){ }

if(window.hasOwnProperty("somePropOrMethod")){ }

if("somePropOrMethod" in window){ }

if(!!window.somePropOrMethod) { }
```

Which one should I use, and why?
Is it all up to personal preference or are there subtle differences between them?

Comment: I would suggest you to check what jquery and other libraries uses internally, that I guess is most recommended and also cross-browser compatible.

Comment: The 1st option can be rewritten as just if(window.somePropOrMethod​ !== undefined){ }

Comment: @Kniganapolke: Not always. You can do `undefined = 42` and then your check would be false, but the `typeof` check would still return true. Note that in modern HTML5 browsers, you can't overwrite `undefined`, as it's not settable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation, and how stringent you want your test to be.

1. Doesn't check that the `somePropOrMethod` attribute is defined on the specific object; it only checks it's in the inheritance chain. Normally this won't matter; especially when checking on `window.` It does however, specifically check the "somePropOrMethod" attribute is **not** `undefined`

   ```
   function Foo() {

   }
   Foo.prototype.bar = 4;
   Foo.prototype.baz = undefined;

   var x = new Foo();

   typeof x.bar​ !== "undefined"; // true, but "x" doesn't actually have a bar attribute; it's in the inheritance chain
   typeof x.baz​ !== "undefined"; // false
   ```
2. Checks the whether the specific object holds the attribute and excludes the inheritance chain from it's search; but it doesn't check the `somePropOrMethod` isn't undefined.

   ```
   window.foo = undefined;
   window.hasOwnProperty("foo"); // true; but it's undefined

   // any properties on window.__proto__ will return false
   ```
3. The same as the first, except it doesn't check against `undefined`; it just checks the object has *some* member (which could be undefined).
4. This checks the object, and it's inheritance chain (i.e. #1 and #3 territory), but is only checking for a *truthy* value;

   ```
   window.foo = false;
   window.bar = 0;
   window.baz = null;

   !!window.foo; // false
   !!window.bar; // false
   !!window.baz; // false
   ```

---

Of course, what you *should* be doing is if you want a *method*, you should check it's a function;

```
if(typeof window.someMethod​ !== "function"){ } // specifically check for a function
```

and you should do the same for other attributes (`string`, `number` etc, or even use the `instanceof` keyword).

Comment: Wouldn't the final one ((!!window.somePropOrMethod) return false when the property exists but has a value of false?

Answer (score 1):

The first will tell you if a property is defined or not. It can exist without being defined.

The second will tell you if the object has the property directly (but not if it inherits it through the prototype).

The third will tell if you the object has the property at all.

The fourth will tell if you if the has a true value (which `{ number_of_children: 0 }` isn't).

Comment: I wonder how we can have an existing undefined property in an object. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Great thanks, I was a bit quick when posting and added a fourth option to the mix - but I guess this one only evaluates to non-falsy value, correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the third return false when the property exists but has a value of false or which evaluates to false?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It tells you if an object has a property, not if the value of that property is true.

Answer (score 1):

- `if(typeof window.somePropOrMethod​ !== "undefined"){ }`

checking if `somePropOrMethod` is a property of `window` and its value is anything but `undefined`.
[ checking directly on the object aswell as in its prototype chain ]

- `if(window.hasOwnProperty("somePropOrMethod")){ }`

checking if `somePropOrMethod` exists *explicitly* on the object itself (`window`), *regardless of its value* (in difference to #1)
[ checking only directly on the object]

- `if("somePropOrMethod" in window){ }`

checking if `somePropOrMethod` can be found on the object itself **or** its prototype chain, *regardless of its value* (in difference to #1)
[ checking directly on the object aswell as in its prototype chain ]

- `if(!!window.somePropOrMethod) { }`

what happens here is to grab the value of `somePropOrMethod` and turn that into a boolean value. If `somePropOrMethod` is `undefined` or any other *falsy value*, the outcome will always be `false`, otherwise its `true`
[ checking directly on the object aswell as in its prototype chain ]